# Game crashes while running with wine

Tags: wine, games

I have installed Dragon Ages: Origins on my Ubuntu 14.04. Everything went well, and I can start the game and enter the main menu. However when I select "New Game" it crashes. I can change options or watch the credits. Here's the console output of wine:

```
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
err:d3d:resource_init Out of adapter memory
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000002 at address 0x86bdec (thread 002b), starting debugger...
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000002 in 32-bit code (0x0086bdec).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:0086bdec ESP:0529d060 EBP:545df6b8 EFLAGS:00210206(  R- --  I   - -P- )
 EAX:00000002 EBX:00021cc0 ECX:0529d050 EDX:0529d094
 ESI:471204b0 EDI:00000008
Stack dump:
0x0529d060:  00000000 0529d094 00000000 11950942
0x0529d070:  0529d1b8 545df538 0529d1b4 00000001
0x0529d080:  0529d120 00a8ca0b ffffffff 005828e7
0x0529d090:  545df6b8 00000000 00000002 00000001
0x0529d0a0:  7bc37200 00000000 1195099e 000274e0
0x0529d0b0:  0529d1b4 575029b0 00000000 000149e8
Backtrace:
=>0 0x0086bdec in daorigins (+0x46bdec) (0x545df6b8)
0x0086bdec: movl    0x0(%eax),%ecx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (149 modules)
PE    340000-  3fd000   Deferred        fmodex
PE    400000-  dbb000   Export          daorigins
PE    dc0000- 1169000   Deferred        d3dx9_36
PE   1170000- 1192000   Deferred        nxcharacter
PE   11a0000- 11b1000   Deferred        physxloader
PE   11c0000- 1234000   Deferred        nxcooking
PE   1240000- 1298000   Deferred        speedtreert
PE   12a0000- 13be000   Deferred        umbra
PE   5c40000- 60a5000   Deferred        physxcore
PE   60b0000- 611e000   Deferred        cudart32_41_22
PE  10000000-10047000   Deferred        fmod_event
PE  18000000-18033000   Deferred        binkw32
PE  78130000-781cb000   Deferred        msvcr80
ELF 7b800000-7ba5b000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5b000   \               kernel32
ELF 7ba88000-7bc00000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7bc00000-7bcdb000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcdb000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
PE  7c420000-7c4a7000   Deferred        msvcp80
ELF 7c4d6000-7c51f000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7c4e0000-7c51f000   \               dsound
ELF 7c51f000-7c591000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7c591000-7c600000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-4.0.so
ELF 7c713000-7c72b000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7c72b000-7c757000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7c7e4000-7c7ed000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7c7ed000-7c821000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7c821000-7c828000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7c828000-7c832000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7c832000-7c83d000   Deferred        libjson-c.so.2
ELF 7c83d000-7c88c000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7c8a8000-7c8d0000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>
  \-PE  7c8b0000-7c8d0000   \               winepulse
ELF 7c8d0000-7c8f2000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c8e0000-7c8f2000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7c8f2000-7c967000   Deferred        ddraw<elf>
  \-PE  7c900000-7c967000   \               ddraw
ELF 7cd90000-7cddb000   Deferred        dinput<elf>
  \-PE  7cda0000-7cddb000   \               dinput
ELF 7cddb000-7ce12000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7ce5a000-7ce65000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7ce65000-7ce82000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7cf6b000-7cf79000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7cf79000-7cf81000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7cf81000-7cfa4000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7cfa4000-7d517000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF 7d517000-7d520000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d520000-7d56b000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d56b000-7d575000   Deferred        libnih-dbus.so.1
ELF 7d575000-7d58e000   Deferred        libnih.so.1
ELF 7d58e000-7d5ac000   Deferred        libcgmanager.so.0
ELF 7d5ac000-7d5bf000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7d5bf000-7d5cd000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7d5cd000-7d5d0000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7d5d0000-7d5d7000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7d5d7000-7d5ef000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7d5ef000-7d64f000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d68f000-7d700000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d6a0000-7d700000   \               setupapi
ELF 7d8d9000-7d8e0000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7d8e0000-7d8e4000   Deferred        libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
ELF 7da01000-7da05000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7da05000-7da09000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7da09000-7da0f000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7da0f000-7da12000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7da12000-7da16000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7da16000-7da3b000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7da20000-7da3b000   \               imm32
ELF 7da3b000-7da72000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7da40000-7da72000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7da72000-7da78000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7da78000-7da83000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7da83000-7da93000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7da93000-7da97000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7da97000-7daa2000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7daa2000-7daad000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7daad000-7dab3000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7dab3000-7dab7000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7dab7000-7dabe000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7dabe000-7dac2000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7dac2000-7dae4000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7dae4000-7dc18000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7dc18000-7dc2b000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7dc2d000-7dc45000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7dc47000-7dcd9000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dc50000-7dcd9000   \               winex11
ELF 7dd58000-7dd81000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dd81000-7ddbc000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7ddbc000-7dde4000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7dde4000-7ddfe000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7ddfe000-7de9e000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7de9e000-7dec0000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
ELF 7dec0000-7dee5000   Deferred        libncurses.so.5
ELF 7df01000-7e037000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7df20000-7e037000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e037000-7e146000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e050000-7e146000   \               opengl32
ELF 7e146000-7e286000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7e150000-7e286000   \               wined3d
ELF 7e286000-7e2c3000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7e290000-7e2c3000   \               d3d9
ELF 7e2c3000-7e2df000   Deferred        dinput8<elf>
  \-PE  7e2d0000-7e2df000   \               dinput8
ELF 7e2df000-7e2fb000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7e2e0000-7e2fb000   \               wsock32
ELF 7e2fb000-7e3a3000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e310000-7e3a3000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e3a3000-7e3b7000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e3b0000-7e3b7000   \               psapi
ELF 7e3b7000-7e4be000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3c0000-7e4be000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e4be000-7e538000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e4d0000-7e538000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e538000-7e76b000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e550000-7e76b000   \               shell32
ELF 7e76b000-7e7a1000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e770000-7e7a1000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e7a1000-7e7c7000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e7b0000-7e7c7000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7e7c7000-7e7f4000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e7d0000-7e7f4000   \               netapi32
ELF 7e7f4000-7e81f000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e800000-7e81f000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e81f000-7e8a0000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e830000-7e8a0000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e8a0000-7e9dc000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e8c0000-7e9dc000   \               ole32
ELF 7e9dc000-7ea4e000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9f0000-7ea4e000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ea4e000-7eb6b000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea60000-7eb6b000   \               gdi32
ELF 7eb6b000-7ecc5000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb80000-7ecc5000   \               user32
ELF 7ecc5000-7ed7f000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7ecd0000-7ed7f000   \               winmm
ELF 7ef7f000-7ef8c000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef8c000-7ef98000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef98000-7efb1000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7efb1000-7efba000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7efba000-7f000000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF b7413000-b75c1000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF b75c1000-b75c6000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF b75c7000-b75e3000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF b75e3000-b75fd000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  b75f0000-b75fd000   \               version
ELF b75ff000-b77b4000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF b77b6000-b77d8000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF b77d8000-b77d9000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\Program Files\Dragon Age\bin_ship\daorigins.exe
    00000040    0
    0000003f   -1
    00000027    1
    0000000d    1
    0000003e    2
    0000003d    2
    0000003c    2
    0000003b   15
    0000003a   15
    00000039    0
    00000038    0
    00000037    0
    00000036   15
    00000035    0
    00000034   -1
    00000033    0
    00000032    0
    00000031    0
    00000030    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0 <==
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    00000043    0
    00000026    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001a    0
    00000018    0
    00000016    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 mscorsvw.exe
    0000001c    0
    0000001b    0
    00000019    0
    00000013    0
00000014 explorer.exe
    0000002a    0
    00000015    0
0000001d winedevice.exe
    00000025    0
    00000022    0
    00000021    0
    0000001e    0
00000023 plugplay.exe
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000024    0
```

I googled for this problem but it seems that in the ones I googles the backtrace showed a problem with some particular library, but here it is the exe file itself.

The list of packages I have installed in winetricks:

```
d3dx10
d3dx9
d3dx9_26
d3dx9_28
d3dx9_31
d3dx9_35
d3dx9_36
d3dx9_39
d3dx9_42
d3dx9_43
d3dxof
directx9
dotnet20
dotnet30(after dotnet20)
mfc42
msvcirt
physx
vcrun2005
vcrun2008
vcrun6
vcrun6sp6
xact
xact_jun2010
xinput
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem.
Because my embedded video card's memory wasn't enough I had to put a setting in winetricks so that by default my video card memory is 500 MB.

Comment: Instead of adding 'SOLVED' to the title, you can use the tick box next to the answer to close your question. Also, you can add how you did it [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10457) to help other users.

Comment: I tried to use the tick box but the system said it must pass 3 days before I can accept my own answer